# Python - White Spaces

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've made a program as follows:

```
x = input('Message? ')
x = x[::3]
for i in x:
  print(i, end=' ')
```

it's supposed to give me the letters of input (every third letter) which it does, although it also prints a white space at the end which I have been unable to get rid of. I've tried everything including the `.rstrip` and `[:-1]` with no luck

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are telling `print()` to print that whitespace with `end=' '`.

Instead of calling `print()` repeatedly, pass in the whole list in one go:

```
print(*x)
```

Now each element of `x` is printed as a *separate argument*, using the default 1-space separator, and a newline as `end`.

Outside of passing in the elements as separate arguments to `print()`, you can also use [`str.join()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) to build one string with separators; this does require that all elements in `x` are strings or you'd need to explicitly convert them:

```
print(' '.join(x))
```

Comment: also, for future reference, what exactly does the * tell the program to do?

Comment: @user3879060: it unpacks `x` into separate arguments. See [What does \*\* (double star) and \* (star) do for Python parameters?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36901)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
x = input('Message? ')
x = x[::3]
print(' '.join(x[::3]))
```

`join` lets you put a space between adjacent characters, leaving out the trailing white-space